# I use eof() to read find but get into an infinite loop

Tags: c++, infinite-loop, eof

```
void StudentArrayV4::add_from(istream &infile) {
    Student temp;
    string name;
    getline(infile, name, ':');
    temp.set_name(name);
    int id;
    infile >> id;
    temp.set_id(id);
    double score;
    while (infile >> score)
    {
        temp.add_exam_score(score);
    }
    add(temp);
    if (name != "")
    {
        infile.ignore();
        infile.clear();
    }
}

int StudentArrayV4::add_all_from( istream& infile ) {
    while (!infile.eof())
    {
        add_from(infile);
        number_of_students++;
    }
    return number_of_students;
}
```

I want to use the function add_all_from to add Students to the array but it gets in an infinite loop. I don't understand why eof() doesn't work in this case.

Comment: What is your understanding of how `eof` works, and why?

Comment: Maybe change the function to return `false` when there is no more data. Ex: `if (!getline(infile, name, ':')) return false;`

Comment: And then change `while (!infile.eof()) { add_from(infile);` to `while (add_from(infile)) {` Also remember to return true at the last line of add_from() to indicate success.